# Changing default route after a user is logged in

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I change the default route after a user is logged in? I'm using the CodeIgniter framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than changing the default route, you could simply have your controller act differently if they are logged in. Something like:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
  public function index()
  {
    if($logged_in) {
      $this->load->view('authenticated');
    } else {
      $this->load->view('guest');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default route with

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'route';
```

in [application/config/routes.php](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#default)